# GroovyRowresult object returns different kinds of values when calling size() depending on how object was instantiated

Tags: groovy

Using Groovy: Not sure if this is intended behavior, but when using size() as applied to a GroovyRowresult object, it will return the number of rows in the object if the object was created by a call to {Sql object}.rows(sql_select_text). However if the GroovyRowresult object was created by a call to {Sql object}.firstRow(sql_select_text), it will return the number of *fields* in the returned record. Problem seems to be that the returned value of a call to {GroovyRowresult object}.size() is determined by how the GroovyRowresult object came into being and not anything else that would be an obvious or clear distinction. Is this intended behavior or not? I can't find it referred to in the Groovy documantation even for the most current ver. of Groovy. Code example:

```
/*
 Using HyperSQL for database implementation for test, so you need the
 HSQLDB package from http://hsqldb.org/ to run this test in the Groovy
 runtime classpath or explode the hsqldb.jar file into the same directory as this
 .groovy script.
*/

import groovy.sql.Sql

memCon = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:hsqldb:mem", "SA", "","org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver")

memCon.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TBL")
memCon.execute("""create table TBL ( 
 AAA    VARCHAR(50),
 BBB    VARCHAR(50)
)""")

sql = "INSERT INTO TBL VALUES ('123', 'ABC')"
memCon.execute(sql)
sql = "INSERT INTO TBL VALUES ('456', 'ABC')"
memCon.execute(sql)
sql = "INSERT INTO TBL VALUES ('789', 'ABC')"
memCon.execute(sql)

sql = "select * from TBL"

rows = memCon.rows(sql)
println '(.rows) rows.size() = ' + rows.size()  // returns 3

rows = memCon.firstRow(sql)
println '(.firstRow) rows.size() = ' + rows.size() // returns 2
```

To test: Save code list above to a file named "test.groovy".  Place it in the same directory as the hsqldb.jar file (if you altered your Groovy runtime classpath to include a reference to it) or its exploded file structure and run it with "groovy test.groovy".

I submitted this issue for review by the Groovy gods; guess I'll have to see what they say.  The issue is found [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-5896).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`memCon.rows` [returns](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#rows%28java.lang.String%29) a `List<GroovyRowResult>`

`memCon.firstRow` [returns](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#firstRow%28groovy.lang.GString%29) a `GroovyRowResult`

So the first `size` call gets the size of the List (the number of rows)

The second `size` call gets the size of the `GroovyRowResult` (the number of fields)

Comment: Tim, Thank you for pointing this out; that is a big distinction.  Even if this isn't really a bug, I hope that by having this particularity mentioned here on StackOverflow that it will save someone else some grief.

Comment: @MattCampbell agreed :-)  Glad I could help clear up the distinction :-)